# Navigate to a XAML page in a different assembly in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigation

I have a XAML page in a separate Windows Phone class library.  The library is included in my VS solution and referenced from my app project.  Let's say the page is called **TestPage.xaml** and it's in the root folder of my library called **SharedPages**.

I'd like to navigate to this page in my app using the NavigationService.  I found [this post](http://cisforcoder.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/navigating-to-pages-in-different-assembly-in-windows-phone-7/) which suggests using this URI format:

```
/{assemblyName};component/{pathToResource}
```

So I'm trying something like this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SharedPages;component/TestPage.xaml"));
```

When I run this I get the following exception:

**Navigation is only supported to relative URIs that are fragments, or begin with '/', or which contain ';component/'.**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like the URI needs to be created as a relative URI.  This works:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SharedPages;component/TestPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Thank you.  I found there cannot be any space between ";" and "component".

Answer (score 4):

Hey I don't think it's your case, but it's good to review the generated assembly name.

**Option 1)**
Incorrect Assembly name

The following format:

```
/{assemblyName};component/{pathToResource}
```

The assembly name can be checked it in the tab properties of the project. I remember a guy who has renamed the project but not the assembly and that was a reason because of the navigation was failing.

**Option 2)**

Dot separator in your assembly name.

I don't know the real reason of this, but I took me some time to found it. The name of the assembly must not have any dot as separator. I guess the Uri parse will incorrectly the Uri. For example I had an assembly called: "Com.Hmb.Prax"  and I got the following exception:

```
Navigation is only supported to relative URIs that are fragments, or begin with '/', or which contain ';component/'.
Parameter name: uri
```

Once I rename my dll to "ComHmbPrax" it worked well.
Herber

Comment: This is really annoying that there cannot be a dot in the assembly.  I was hoping by Windows Phone 8 it would be fixed, but is not... Thanks for pointing this out, it's not easily found elsewhere!

Comment: @Redth Hi guys! How did you know that dots are forbidden in URI paths? Have you found any workaround for this problem? I have two projects with assemblies with dots in their names, namespaces names, Mercurial repositories names and so on. The idea of changing everything I mentioned disappoints me.